# Magento 2: Configuration not working when installed extension Ebizmarts_MailChimp?

Tags: magento2, extensions, mailchimp

i installed this extension than after configuration page not working!

showing below error :

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/ploma/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 63

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/ploma/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 63
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command:

```
bin/magento rm -rf generated/* var/* && chmod -R 777 generated
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is down to the extension you have installed not setting the correct tab ID within the extension if you go into the etc/adminhtml/ folder and edit system.xml just below the  variable you should see something like

```
<tab id="vendor_name_here" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
```

if there is on make sure that the options are associated to this tab. can you advise on the extension in question so i can take a look at it